# Create a array for this json in php

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a array for the following json code.

```
{
 "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
 "homeMobileNetworkCode": 260,
 "radioType": "gsm",
 "carrier": "T-Mobile",
 "cellTowers": [
  {
   "cellId": 39627456,
   "locationAreaCode": 40495,
   "mobileCountryCode": 310,
   "mobileNetworkCode": 260,
   "age": 0,
   "signalStrength": -95
  }
 ],
 "wifiAccessPoints": [
  {
   "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
   "signalStrength": 8,
   "age": 0,
   "signalToNoiseRatio": -65,
   "channel": 8
  },
  {
   "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AC",
   "signalStrength": 4,
   "age": 0
  }
 ]
}
```

I have tried with the following but it is showing parsing error in google maps geomatic api

```
$a = array("homeMobileCountryCode" => 310,
    "homeMobileNetworkCode" => 260,
    "radioType" => "gsm",
    "carrier" => "T-Mobile");

$jsonVal =  json_encode($a);
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: the error shows that you don't have to send the data in this format. Just check in google which kind of encoded data google maps api needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's json_encode does not wrap integers with double quotes, which is invalid json. Try this:

```
$a = array("homeMobileCountryCode" => "310",
    "homeMobileNetworkCode" => "260",
    "radioType" => "gsm",
    "carrier" => "T-Mobile");

$jsonVal =  json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried with doublu quote also.Still it is not parsing

Comment: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } ], "code": 400, "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } }-- this is the error i'm getting

Comment: if you are using curl to make the request, you might consider  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json') param for curl_setopt_array call.

Answer (score 0):

From json to Array:

```
$array = json_decode(/* json text /*);
```

From Array to Json

```
$json = json_encode(/* array Object */);
```

Answer (score 0):

explanations here but you can skip to clean final code further down.

```
$cellTower1 = array(  "cellId"=> "39627456",
   "locationAreaCode"=> "40495",
   "mobileCountryCode"=> "310",
   "mobileNetworkCode"=> "260",
   "age"=> "0",
   "signalStrength"=> "-95" );

$cellTower2 = array(  "cellId"=> "2222222",
   "locationAreaCode"=> "22222",
   "mobileCountryCode"=> "222",
   "mobileNetworkCode"=> "222",
   "age"=> "22",
   "signalStrength"=> "-22" );
```

Then combine all cell towers

```
  $allCellTowers[] = $cellTower1;

  $allCellTowers[] = $cellTower2; 
//etc... or could be in a loop
```

Now for MAC addresses and wifiAccessPoints.

```
 $macAddress1 = array (
   "macAddress"=> "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
   "signalStrength" => "8",
   "age" => "0",
   "signalToNoiseRatio" => "-65",
   "channel" => "8"
  );

 $macAddress2 = array (
   "macAddress" => "01:23:45:67:89:AC",
   "signalStrength" => "4",
   "age" => "0"
  );

 $macAddress3 = etc...
```

just as for `cellTower1, cellTower2` the macaddresses 1 & 2 above can be populated with a loop.
Adding them to `wifiAccessPoints` also can be done in a loop but it done manually below just so you understand.

```
  $wifiAccessPoints[] = $macAddress1;

  $wifiAccessPoints[] = $macAddress2;
```

finally the other elements all go in the resulting array to encode

```
$myarray = array( "homeMobileCountryCode"=> "310",
                  "homeMobileNetworkCode"=> "260",
                  "radioType"=> "gsm",
                  "carrier"=> "T-Mobile",
                  "cellTowers"=>$allCellTowers, 
                  "wifiAccessPoints" => $wifiAccessPoints
            );
$json = json_encode($myarray);
```

IN CLEAN CODE IT IS

```
$cellTower1 = array(  "cellId"=> "39627456",
   "locationAreaCode"=> "40495",
   "mobileCountryCode"=> "310",
   "mobileNetworkCode"=> "260",
   "age"=> "0",
   "signalStrength"=> "-95" );

$allCellTowers[] = $cellTower1;

 $macAddress1 = array (
   "macAddress"=> "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
   "signalStrength" => "8",
   "age" => "0",
   "signalToNoiseRatio" => "-65",
   "channel" => "8"
  );

 $macAddress2 = array (
   "macAddress" => "01:23:45:67:89:AC",
   "signalStrength" => "4",
   "age" => "0"
  );

 $wifiAccessPoints[] = $macAddress1;

 $wifiAccessPoints[] = $macAddress2;

 $myarray = array( "homeMobileCountryCode"=> "310",
                   "homeMobileNetworkCode"=> "260",
                   "radioType"=> "gsm",
                   "carrier"=> "T-Mobile",
                   "cellTowers"=>$allCellTowers, 
                   "wifiAccessPoints" => $wifiAccessPoints
             );

 //note that you have your first key missing though in your example

 $json = json_encode($myarray);
```